# unfortunately, app has stopped on calling actionModeStarted

Tags: android

I am creating a menu to show on top of the screen while longpress in webview.

But I am getting a message `"unfortunately, app has stopped"`, then app closed.

I created mymenu in xml(fn.xml) and placed it in `\res\menu\fn.xml`

fn.xml file:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.fn.MainActivity" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/mark"       
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:onClick="onContextualMenuItemClicked"
        android:title="Mark">
    </item>

</menu>
```

My MainActivity class code is below

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    WebView webview;    
    private ActionMode mActionMode = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webview.loadUrl("http://www.myurl.com");        
    }

    @Override
    public void onActionModeStarted(ActionMode mode) {
        if (mActionMode == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "stateVal",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mActionMode = mode;
            Menu menu = mode.getMenu();
            mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.fn, menu);
        }
        super.onActionModeStarted(mode);
    }

    public void onContextualMenuItemClicked(MenuItem item) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

my Log screen shot

[image]
May I know what is missing here?

Comment: your crash log is missing here ;). Please post it.

Comment: Its working fine in AVD, when install it in mobile using .apk, it shows this message..

Comment: I updated with log screen, pls take a look..

Comment: Post the logcat from the device

Comment: Screenshot of the logcat will not help. Post the log of the crash/exception.

Comment: This is what I m getting, and there is no exception..